# my TEXMFVAR folder is not readable, is my texlive installation ok?

Tags: texlive

I use texlive as packaged for suse tumbleweed.
As i faced some problems with caching I tried

```
kpsewhich --expand-var '$TEXMFVAR'
```

which results in `/var/lib/texmf` which is not writable.
Most probably this is the source of my caching problems.

In various sites I read what TEXMFVAR is:

- The (personal) tree used by texconfig, updmap-user and fmtutil-user to store (cached) runtime data such as format ﬁles and generated map ﬁles.
- default: `~/.texlive/texmf-var`   explanation: updmap and fmtutil (sys mode) to store (cached) runtime data

Hm, I think this does not fit.
I don't have a `~/.texlive` folder.
What I do have is a folder `~/.cache/texmf` with sole subfolder `fonts`.

My first question is, whether my distribution is ok, or plausible.

Comment: Plausible, but evidently bad. Do not be afraid to create directories in your home folder. And, you may be able to re-direct where TeX looks for things, without admin privilege. Try this (may or may not work): Edit your ~/.bashrc file (or create one). Write `export TEXMFVAR=$HOME/.texlive/texmf-var` then reboot. You can do that for other TeX directories, too.

Comment: seems to work. 
But I think, better the texlive installation does this setting, right? 
At least my caching problem disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

Since the OP has it working now, I will promote my comment to an answer.

First: Whenever you install TeXlive, or upgrade to a later year, be sure that the binaries are on your PATH. A few systems may do that automatically, if you install from the operating system rather than directly from TUG. However, the automatic PATH is probably not enable until re-boot. So, re-boot.

Second, TeXlive allows you to state its internal environment variables directly, as part of the environment. Then, it will only use its own variables, if it cannot find what it needs in yours. This is the method that worked for the OP.

For example, suppose TeX is looking for files in `/path/to/somehwere`, but they are in `/this/other/place`. You can do:

```
export TEXWHATEVER=/this/other/place
```

in your user `$HOME/.bashrc` file, then reboot. Now TeX expects its `TEXWHATEVER` environment in `/this/other/place`. In my own setup, the distro TeX is so different from TUG, that I manually define TEXMFROOT this way.

This is especially effective if (as with the OP) TeX needs to write there, but you do not have write privileges. You can re-direct to a somewhere in your home directory, where you do have write privileges.

This is not the only solution. There is also `usermode` which directs many things to a directory of your choice, in user home. The `tlmgr` program help will show you what to do. In general `usermode` is a better approach.